# extend side menu line for bootstrap page content

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Currently, the line dividing the content and the side menu stops at the side menu's content. However, the content will be longer than the side menu. It makes the page uneven. I tried manipulating the page-content d-flex but i am not successful.

Using template from https://bootstrapious.com/p/admin-template

Below is the code for the side menu

```
  <div class="page-content d-flex align-items-stretch">
   <nav class="side-navbar">
      <!-- Sidebar Navidation Menus-->
      <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html"> <i class="icon-home"></i>Home </a></li>
        <li><a routerLink="/dashboard"> <i class="icon-picture"></i>Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a routerLink="/tasknotification"> <i class="icon-padnote"></i>Task Management</a></li>
        <li><a routerLink="/candidate"> <i class="icon-user"></i>Candidate Management </a></li>
        <li><a routerLink="/job"> <i class="icon-interface-windows"></i>Job Management</a></li>
        <li><a href="#exampledropdownDropdown" aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="collapse"> <i
              class="icon-interface-windows"></i>Example dropdown </a>
          <ul id="exampledropdownDropdown" class="collapse list-unstyled ">
            <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to see your code online?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mason_yy/m3tbo27q/

But the side menu is not full for some reason. Only can see a small part of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modify media query

```
@media (max-width: 1199px)
nav.side-navbar {
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
nav.side-navbar {
    text-align: left;
    min-width: 250px;
}
.page-content {
    min-width: calc(100% - 250px);
}
```

This way side-menu won't collapse. As I saw your fiddle I think that might work